# Is it ok to use temporary tables in sql interview?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

When doing an online/on-ground coding interview for SQL is it ok to use temporary table?
Say for something like this, the sub query made into a temporary table could be easy to build upon other queries that may be asked in the preceding questions:

```
use employees;
set @from_date = "1999-01-01";
set @to_date = "9999-01-01";

SELECT dept_name, max(salary)
FROM 
(
   SELECT d.dept_name, e.*, s.salary, s.from_date, s.to_date, de.from_date as defd, de.to_date as detd FROM employees e
   INNER JOIN salaries s ON e.emp_no = s.emp_no AND s.to_date >= @to_date AND s.from_date >=@from_date
   INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON e.emp_no = de.emp_no AND de.to_date >= @to_date AND de.from_date >=@from_date
   INNER JOIN departments d ON de.dept_no = d.dept_no
) t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Also, when should temporary tables be used? Is it a good practice to use it for one time ad-hoc analysis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my real life (in real life production work) if a join gets to be to much (more then 6-8 tables) or a lot of sub-queries I use temporary tables. But at an interview that may seem a sign of weakness. Use CTE's and windows functions (over) and no one will complain

Comment: and what if the RDBMS system doesn't support CTE? Who says using temp table is a sign of weekness

Comment: Sometimes the interviewer thinks that complexity = knowledgeable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's fine using a temporary table (you can go for local or session temporary table and not a global one). If the RDBMS system you are working on supports CTE then that would be a best choice but not all supports it like `MySQL` .. in which case your best bet is to use a temp table.

Other RDBMS systems like `SQL Server` provides much more option like `Table Type Variable` which can be used in same manner

Comment: This is a SQL Server forum.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits - the question is tagged with both sql server AND mysql.

Comment: Missed it sorry.